# How can I disable ValueBoxEditorDecorator<String>?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwt-editors

I'd like to have read-only editor so I disable every control in it. But I can't do that with ValueBoxEditorDecorator. Do you guys have any ideas how I can disable it ?

There is `ValueBoxBase<T> peer` inside the class but it's obviously private.

Comment: It highly depends how you iterate over your sub-editors.

Comment: I iterate through them manually. I added `public interface Enableable { void setEnable(boolean enable); }` which I implement in every editor. Would you suggest more elegant solution than the one I described in my answer ?

Comment: No, your self-answer is the correct approach (to me). You could try something around an `EditorVisitor` but I'm not sure it'd be worth the complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I can add ID to inner widget like this

```
<e:ValueBoxEditorDecorator ui:field="cellPhoneNumber" stylePrimaryName="{style.forform}">
    <e:valuebox>
        <g:TextBox ui:field="cellPhoneNumberText" width="100%" stylePrimaryName="{style.forform}"/>
    </e:valuebox>
</e:ValueBoxEditorDecorator>
```

and then call `cellPhoneNumberText.setEnable()`.

The only downside to it is extra definition of field in my class whihc also has to be marked with `@Ignore` annotation like this

```
@UiField
ValueBoxEditorDecorator<String> cellPhoneNumber;

@Ignore
@UiField
TextBox cellPhoneNumberText;
```